# how to set monitor timeout to "never" using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, settings, sleep

I want to write a script that will change the power settings for "turn off the display" and "put the computer to sleep" to "never" (see attached screenshot).
I know how to set times for the above using:

```
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac [time]
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-dc [time]
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac [time]
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-dc [time]
```

but I can't find how to set it to "never".

what is the syntax I need to use?

thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

`powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0`

Per this, my favorite reference for missing help switch/parameter information:
http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html

> Setting any value to 0 will set the timeout=Never

Thanks to Cristian, official documentation with additional parameters is [currently available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I thought about trying 0, but feared that it might set the screen-off time to zero and practically lock me out :)

Comment: Documentation is also available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options